# preventing pasting images in ckeditor xp:inputRichText control xpages

Tags: ckeditor, xpages

I have followed the steps described in the following blogpost on how to prevent pasting of images in the ckeditor that is used for the xp:inputRichText control on my xpage:

http://camerongregor.com/2016/11/14/preventing-pasting-of-images-in-ckeditor/

If I load my page in the browser console I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined
    at blockimagepaste:1
```

The rich text control is displayed properly.

The Domino server is on FP8.

What can be the cause of this error message and how can I apply a workaround?

Comment: It may be a timing issue. Perhaps the JavaScript function is being triggered before the CKEditor JS module is being loaded. CKEDITOR will be a JS variable set up when that is loaded, assuming the CKEditor is being used for the rich text component in the theme you're using. You can check that by loading a page your code and inspecting the JS, which should also allow you to drill down into the module and confirm CKEDITOR is still the variable name (I'm not aware of any reason it would change, but that would depend on whoever develops CKEditor (not IBM as far as I'm aware).

Comment: well, I noticed when I referenced the library via the resources tab in xpages the console complained that Editor was not an object in the DOM. So I referenced the script at the bottom of the Xpage as a normal script reference and then the console did not complain any more.